# Using Process Builder to Create an Event in A Public Calendar

Tags: profile, process-builder, event, home-page-layout, public-calendar

I am working with Process Builder and trying to set the "Assigned To" to a public calendar. I have created and shared a caldendar with several users and I am trying to get an event to show up on their calendar feeds in their user profile. Is this possible? Or is the only way for them to see those public calendar events to change their calendar view to "Public Calendar" instead of the default?

Process Builder is sending the event to the public calendar (I got that to work), but does salesforce not display those events in the individual user's calendar feed as well as the public calendar? Is there a setting you can turn on to do so?